# Custom scalebar with half-segments in QGIS

Tags: qgis, style, qgis-3, scale-bar, standards

I am trying to recreate a scalebar thats part of a norwegian standard (NS3039) in QGIS.

QGIS makes these half-segments for negative values (highlighted in red in  the picture below [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DNKC.png), but I want these half-segments for the first positive segment, as shown in the picture at the bottom [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KX42Y.png)

The original from QGIS:

[image: original qgis scalebar]

The target scalebar:

[image: target scalebar]

Any idea how I can create this in the Print Layout in QGIS?

Comment: Do you want this scalebar to be used in the composer, or on the map canvas as "decoration".

Comment: In the Print Layout/print composer to show on the finished map. I edited my question to clearify this

Comment: Possible workaround could be to use the scalebar provided by QGis, but add the numbers manually.

Comment: Or you could put a second scalebar (25m increments, one segment, no labels) on top of the first scalebar.

Comment: Might be worth making a feature request https://issues.qgis.org/projects/qgis/issues/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A very ugly solution based on csk comment about a second scale bar, but it achieves the goal and it could be no harmful in a good template.

1.- First create a scale bar with the desired lenght on the right and shape (in this case a double box). In this case lenght 5 and unit 100 m
[image]

2. Create a second bar, but now with length two on the right and half of the unit of the first one, in the example 50 m. The trick is to invert the colors of fill and secondary, and change front to 100% transparent 
   [image]
3. Finally, the second scale bar has to be placed on top of the first one. This is easy done with the snap that operates in the printer composer, but if not the position and size can provide full control. 
   [image: 3]

Comment: Thanks. I'll do it like this. It looks correct at least

Answer (score -2):

You need to set the **Left** segments to 0, as seen in this screen shot.

[image]

Comment: You are not answering the questions about the half-segments on the possitive side of the scale bar

Comment: not sure you can do that

Comment: I agree, I do not see it is achievable with the 2.18 at least

Comment: Left=0 only removes these half-segments and doesnt push them to the positive side. And I am using the latests QGIS 3, but I haven't seen any options there either